# Exclude category from Tag Template

Tags: categories, templates, exclude

I'm trying to exclude a category from my tag template. Searching gives me nothing and kinda stuck. When I add the code below to my tag template it shows all posts... and I really would like to show all posts with a specific tag, but not the ones from category ID 433.

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array('cat' => -433, ) ); ?>
                        <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
                        <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
```

So, this is not working :) Also tried this one:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__not_in' => array( 433 ) ) );
```

Also showing all posts. Hope anyone got an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a normal loop in your tag template like this

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
    //add content code or template
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And then using the `pre_get_posts` filter like this

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_tag() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-433' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Comment: never checked the pre_get_posts filter. Works like a charm! Many thanks Stims!

Comment: Glad to hear, pre_get_posts is clutch!